# Differential equation with limit

Tags: calculus

> Find a solution y=f(x) to the differential equation 
>   $$\frac{1}{x^2}y'-\frac{2}{x^3}y+\frac{1}{x^2+x}=0 ,\qquad x>0$$ satisfying
>   $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{x^2}=1$.

I have $y=x^2(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+C)$ so far but can someone please explain the process from beginning to end? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean — do you want to know how to continue from this (to get a solution with the right limit), or to explain everything from the beginning, including how to get you *own* partial solution?

Comment: Oh sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I primarily want someone to confirm if the solution is right and then take the limit.

Answer (score 1):

That limits lets you find $C$. Just evaluate $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=1\iff \ln (x+1)-\ln x +c=1 \iff \lim_{x\to\infty} \ln \left (\frac{x+1}{x}\right )+c=1 \stackrel{\ln x \text{ cont.}}{\iff} \ln \left (\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+1}{x}\right )+c_1=1\iff 0+c=1 \iff c=1$$

So $$y=x^2(\ln (x+1)-\ln x+1)$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+C)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+C=C+\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})$$

But $\frac{x+1}{x} \to 1$, so $\ln(\frac{x+1}{x}) \to 0$, so:

$$C+\lim_{x \to \infty}\ln(\frac{x+1}{x})=C$$

If you put $C=1$ you have $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{y(x)}{x^2}=1$

Answer (score 0):

You've got a solution to the differential equation:

$$
f(x)=x^2(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+C)
$$

but it involves an arbitrary constant $C$.  The limit condition is there so that the constant $C$ is defined to have a particular value - so there's a unique solution rather than a family of solutions differing by a constant.

We have

$$
f(x)/x^2=(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x)+C)
$$

There's only one possible value of $C$ such that the limit of this expression as $x\to\infty$ is $1$.  What is it?  **Hint:** Remember the rules for manipulating logarithms!